# Search Path Not working- Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, search

I have given the search path in Xcode link this,

```
/include/tbb/machine
```

in the User Header Search Path.

still the files are not found

[image]

Comment: `/include`?  Are you sure?  Go to terminal and see what `ls /include` shows.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Terminal shows ,No such file or directory

Comment: So you have your answer, yes?

Comment: Then , How can I set the path,  ?

Comment: Well start by using the correct path.  Only you know what that is.  I am also highly sceptical you even need to add this path, assuming the path is really `/usr/include/tbb` and it follows other `machine` or `arch` directory conventions, as it's not supposed to be exposed to developers directly.

Comment: I have given like this. But , not working. Thanks